# should I change my javascript jquery functions to meteor format?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to meteor. I already have a js file with a series of functions. When I tried a meteor starter project, it seems it have other structures for jquery events. like:

```
Template.body.events({

  'submit .new-task'(event) {
   ...
```

I wonder what is the benefit of rewriting my current js functions in the above format? I want my website works as a mobile app, and I've heard Meteor does that. Is it important to implement the site in the format so I get the best performance and compability?

Comment: @Trueman I added why I bother

Comment: Now it is more obvious what are you trying to achieve. Meteor can be integrated with Apache Cordova to build standalone app (instead of running in browser only) which will be for sure much faster. But jQuery can also be integrated with Cordova:
http://techs.studyhorror.com/cordova-jquery-hello-sample-i-187

Also check:
https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html
https://cordova.apache.org/

So if you are not new to jQuery I am sure you will like the jQuery solution, unless meteor do more "magics", which I am not aware of:)

Comment: You seem to be asking two different unrelated questions here. Meteor starter boilerplate is set with Blaze, the default template system, and what you see here is [events](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps). 

Now, if you'd like to export your application to IOS or Android, please follow the link @Trueman provided.